# UILabel won't change off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

I have a problem that i've trying to figure out for a few days now. Technically I'm trying to change a UILabel text in one view, from a trigger in a button in another view. When the button is in the view where the UILabel is, the label changes without a problem. But when assigning the trigger to a button in another view (even though using the same ViewController class) it won't change the UILabel's text.

Here's the piece of code triggering my button on both cases.

```
- (IBAction)getYearMonth:(UIButton*)sender {

//NSLog(@"Date: %@ 1 %@", sender.titleLabel.text, self.year.text);

//evenCon.eventsCurrentDate.text = @"";

//NSLog(@"%@", evenCon.eventsCurrentDate.text);

//string = sender.currentTitle;
eventsCurrentDate.text = @"hello";
}
```

Excuse my knowledge in objective-c, I started learning two weeks ago.

Edit: I think i need to add this. My views are being displayed without segues, they are childs of a scrollview in the main view controller. (Kind of like the snapchat app effect)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

//loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, (self.view.center.x - (1)), 517);
//[self.loginView addSubview:loginView];

[self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.scrollView setDelegate:self];


[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View3"]];
}
```

"View1" is where the label i'm trying to change is, and "View2" is where my button is.

Comment: have you tried `setNeedsDisplay` or something similar to tell it to redraw when it comes into view? Just a shot in the dark sorry.

Comment: double check to make sure the IBOutlet is hooked up and `eventsCurrentDate` is not `nil`

Comment: try making the UILabel strong and nonatomic, if fails, it will be better if you post the code of both the views and the storyboard , if possible.

Comment: place a breakpoint inside `- (IBAction)getYearMonth:(UIButton*)sender` and make sure that the method is always called. And verify that the label is not `nil` like @DBD suggests.

Comment: @kambala I had previously made some NSLog prints to check if it was working, and it does. I just did a break point as well and it works. This problem truly puzzles me.

Comment: @user3752753 the UILabel is already strong, nonatomic. I will update the main post to display my code.

Comment: @AlexReynolds tried it immediately after you mentioned it, no luck though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are not sending any data to another view. Download Master detail sample code form Xcode (Its in add new project). Look for how they transfer data to another view controller and then display the text it in your label

Comment: I made a small edit on my problem. I'm not using any segues like a master detail sample would, my views are childs of a uiscrollview under a main view controller.

Comment: you can try UINotificationCenter. I understand, passing data between to view controllers are some time too tricky but UINotificationCenter always works for me. There are lots of tutorial on Passing data using UINotificationCenter

Comment: Ohh I just saw your code. Try to use segue because you can easily pass data through segue. Generally I don't recommend using "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" when I need to pass data.

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid that because my app requires to have the scroll view thing. Perhaps you could point me into having the same effect of scrolling through views left and right with segues?

Comment: Like you said, with segues it worked fine. I only had to re-call the main scrollview and that made all views refresh. Now I'm a little afraid of a stack overflow but I'll worry about that later. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use setText

```
[_eventsCurrentDate setText:@"hello"];
```

Comment: That will not do anything different.